# Instantiating Objects Shorthand

Tags: c#

I'm wondering if this is a stupid question but whatever...

Consider:

```
this.dataSourceFacade = new DataSourceFacade();

this.SomeGrid.DataSource = this.dataSourceFacade.GetData();
```

And compare to:

```
this.SomeGrid.DataSource = new DataSourceFacade().GetData();
```

Anything wrong with the second approach assuming that's the only place it gets used?

Richard

Comment: Nothing wrong with that approach.

Comment: Take a look at the MSIL generated when the project is built...I wouldn't be surprised to see both ways generate the same (or nearly the same) MSIL.

Comment: This developer would love to have the time to do that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short and simple: No there is nothing wrong with the second approach... in most cases even preferable because cleaner (no unneeded local variables) and better to read+maintain :-)

Answer (score 0):

The second approach,

```
this.SomeGrid.DataSource = (new DataSourceFacade()).GetData();
```

You will lose the reference to the `DataSourceFacade` object should you need it for later, e.g. set other things, get other things, or call methods of that object.

Comment: Yup but for a lot of cases like loading up a bunch of drop-downs, that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

It does make the code easier to read and maintain in the long run. Also it should be just "fine" to do.

However, you are only creating an instance of the object just to call a single method on it, I would question if that method could be pulled out into a static method instead.

Like this:

```
this.SomeGrid.DataSource = DataSourceFacade.GetDate();
```

Also in the static implementation I would try to not instantiate object instances that wont be used, if at all possible.

Comment: The example's just a simple one, the actual real facades are entirely different beasts in use in all sorts of situations.

Answer (score 0):

well, personally I like to unit test and both approaches are going to limit your ability to do that.

At the very least I would create a factory to do something like this

```
this.SomeGrid.DataSource = DataSourceFacade.GetDataSource();
```

or

```
this.SomeGrid.DataSource = DataSourceFacade.Factory.GetDataSource()
```

At least this way you could add the ability to somehow update your Factory in the future for testing.

Comment: We're pretty much stuck with integration testing but compared to how things were before, that's ok :)

Comment: Yeah, we've all been stuck in that situation before.